# Bash local variables

Tags: bash, shell

How can I declare variables which are local to functions? Regularly declared vars get exported into global scope. Example:

```
$ cat t.sh
function locals_test() 
{
  x="bar"
}

$ echo $x

$ locals_test 
$ echo $x
bar
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `local`:

```
local x=bar
```

Then, `x` will be local to the function. To declare e.g. arrays or numbers, `local` takes the same options as `declare`. Output will be two empty lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
function locals_test() 
{
  local x=bar
}

echo $x
locals_test
echo $x
```